# Making "alias" keyboard shortcuts on Mac (multiple keyboard doning the same thing)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there a way to create "alias" for keyboard shortcuts on Mac? That is, may I map different keyboard shortcuts to the same function? Simply put, let <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> both work as switch-to-next-tab in Firefox. (Note, these keys don't have to be application-specific).

Currently, through the "Shortcuts" tab under `Keyboard` from the System Preference, I can map menu item to a **single** keyboard shortcut. However, this is the end of the story. Though such mappings could even be application-specific, I still cannot assign multiple keyboard shortcuts to the same menu item.

(Particular usage demand: my fingers are quite thick and it is natural for me to press nearby keys when trying to execute a certain keyboard shortcut.)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean like you have shortcutA and shortcutB. Then you want to create shortcutC = A+B? Not sure if thats what you mean or not.

Comment: Oh, I was intending to say, let ShortcutA and Shortcut do THE SAME THING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfect alternative that I finally find is [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). It has the potential to fully specify:

- Global mappings that "summon" `*.app` programs that one can find through the `Application\` folder;
- Program-specific mappings that remap obscure mappings into "comfortable ones". For example:

  - I am used to having `Ctrl + w` to delete a word to the left of the cursor. It is doable in Keyboard Maestro to achieve this for Safari, for example. (I remapped `^w` to work as `Option + Backspace`.)

My only complaint is that: Keyboard Maestro seems to operate on top of a nice GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a great tool to do this: Karabiner for OS X.

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.

You may download it at https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: What specific function/method in this App shall I specify, to achieve, for example: let <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> both work as switch-to-next-tab in Firefox. (Note, these keys don't have to be application-specific).

Comment: Karabiner does not work on 10.12